# Proof that all the vectors $\{u\in \mathbb{R}^n|u^Tv = 0\}$ that are perpendicular to a given vector $v$ can make a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given an undefined number of vectors $\{u_1, u_2,...,u_n,v\}\in V$ and I have to prove that all the vectors that apply the condition:
$$\{u\in \mathbb{R}^n|u^Tv = 0\}$$
make a subspace of $V$.

It's only the second week of the course so it wasn't specifically said, but to my understanding all of these vectors are probably a basis of some space $\mathbb{R}^n$ and if I exclude the vector $v$, all the others that are perpendicular to it are a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

In order to show that I have to make sure two conditions are kept:

1. the group $\{u\in \mathbb{R}^n|u^Tv = 0\}$ is closed under vector addition and closed under scalar multiplication
2. the zero vector is in the group (the group is not empty) **But** I'm not sure whether I need to show that: $$\vec{ 0 }\in \{u_1, u_2,...,u_n\}$$ or that $$\vec{ 0 }\in Span\{u_1, u_2,...,u_n\}$$

Since the result of inner product is a scalar I can tell that: $a = (v^T{u_i}) = 0 \in\mathbb{R} $, so basically $a\cdot{u_i} = \vec{ 0 }$ and therefore it is certainly inside the $Span\{u_1, u_2,...,u_n\}$ , but if my assumption about the vectors being a basis, only the trivial scalar $0$ is the way to create the $\vec{0}$ so it feels wrong.

Showing that the group $\{u\in \mathbb{R}^n|u^Tv = 0\}$ is closed under vector addition and closed under scalar multiplication is easy and trivial, but as for the zero vector I'm not sure what I do is valid or right, and for that I would appreciate guidance.

Comment: Why are the vectors $u_1,\ldots, u_n$ mentioned to begin with? The (claimed) subspace is defined with reference to $v$ only ...

Comment: you're right, it wasn't necessary. I just wanted to show my process of thinking in order to spot what was wrong with my process. that was a part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that

$$\vec 0^T \vec v = 0$$

to be sure that $\vec 0$ is in the subset which is then a subspace.

Comment: So I need to show that the $\vec{0}$ suffices the condition rather that "forcibly" create it out of a scalar product.
Thank you!

Comment: @AviP Yes since $\vec 0$ is always in the span of any set of cectors.